# Option Inspector "Permanent" Change

Tags: output-formatting, options

Whenever the package [`LieART`](https://lieart.hepforge.org/) is loaded using `` << LieART` ``, `CommonDefaultFormatTypes > "Output"` is changed to `TraditionalForm`. This seems to happen by some means that is slightly more permanent than changes I can make.

In particular, after going into the Option Inspector and changing the option back to `StandardForm`, this is what I see:
[image: Option Inspector showing that change to StandardForm is temporary]

After making my change, the corresponding line in the Inspector is bolded and there is a button on the left that I can click to cancel the change and return to the "default" value of `TraditionalForm`. I would have assumed that the `Apply` button in the upper right could be used to make the change into the default value, but it is always greyed out for me. The same behavior is seen if I do something like

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {CommonDefaultFormatTypes, "Output"}] = StandardForm;
```

The change made by `LieART` is not like this; the line is unbolded, there is no button to cancel the change.

Is there a way for me to change this option back to its true default value? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more searching within the documentation, it seems that

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {CommonDefaultFormatTypes, "Output"}] = StandardForm;
```

does the trick.